# Error installing firebase on React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native, error-handling

I am trying to run firebase on React Native, and I keep getting the same error.

> Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app().
> Ensure you have:
>
> 1. imported the 'io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage' module in your 'MainApplication.java' file.
> 2. Added the 'new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage()' line inside of the RN 'getPackages()' method list.

I have tried both of those and it still does not work. React Native is on the latest version and I'm trying to run it on Android.

This is where the error occurs.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { ImageBackground, StyleSheet, Platform, StatusBar, View, Button, Text } from 'react-native';
import Dashboard from './app/screens/Dashboard';
import HomeScreen from './app/screens/HomeScreen';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

function CurrentUser() {
  // Set an initializing state whilst Firebase connects
  const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  // Handle user state changes
  function onAuthStateChanged(user) {
    setUser(user);
    if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
    return subscriber; // unsubscribe on unmount
  }, []);

  if (initializing) return null;

  if (!user) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Login</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Welcome {user.email}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false
        }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="loginapp" component={CurrentUser} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: do manual linking and clean gradle and restart